# How to use include_once in Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, include-path

- My development environment is: Win7, XAMPP 1.8.3.3 VC11.
- include_path in my PHP.ini file is: ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

I have downloaded a package simplehtmldom_1_5 and kept in "C:\xampp\php\PEAR" folder so that my test file "C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php" can include PHP files from this package. My test1.php looks like:

```
<?php
include_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
echo file_get_html('www.google.com')->plaintext;
?>
```

As soon as I type `http://localhost/test1.php`, I get the below error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 15
```

If I move the simplehtmldom_1_5 package from "C:\xampp\php\PEAR" to "C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom_1_5" and then try the above test1.php, I get the below error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 15
```

I have spent considerable time in debugging this but gave up now. Please help where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `file_get_contents` or similar function to open a URL you should specify the full protocol to tell PHP this is web address or external file not a local file.

Therefore,

```
file_get_contents('www.google.com')
```

Should be changed to:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `http://www.google.com` and not a **file** called `www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use http:// with url

```
<?php
include_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com')->plaintext;
?>
```

also you need to check you have file dir(simplehtmldom_1_5) on where test1.php located
like :-

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom_1_5
```